# JavaScript asking a textarea for a specific number

Tags: javascript, animation, input

I´m doing a project right now. And for this I need to move an object to a specific place (by animation). I tried to make a simple input with a button, but it doesnt work at all.
For example if I type 5 into the input the object should move to point 5.
I tried to use if and else but it took away the whole animation..

Maybe I can get help on this platform. It is my first time programming on my own.
T

```
'use strict';



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () 
{
    var boxfünf = 
[
        {
            transform: 'translate(0, 0)',
    },
        {
            transform: 'translate(0px, -480px)',
    },
        {
            transform: 'translate(-180px, -480px)',
    },
        {
            transform: 'translate(0px, -480px)',
    },
        {
            transform: 'translate(0px, 0px)',
    }
];
    var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
    var text = document.getElementById("q");
    
    
document.querySelector('#interaktiv')
        .addEventListener('click', function ()
        {
            circle.animate(boxfünf, {
                iterations: 1,
                fill: 'forwards',
                duration:4000,
            
                
            });
        });
    
});
```

Comment: If you don't have a specific reason to use animate(), I suggest you create your animations in CSS and control them simply by adding class names. Much cleaner JS, less code, and easier execution, in general. If you want to use animate() please give some more details, especially your dom structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to make a simulation of a machine which sorts different objects.

Comment: Try creating a Snippet of the code you've got so we can look at it a bit closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to use this for, but I would go with Bülent Akgül's suggested solution, and use pre-defined classes. I'm listening to an input event, and overwriting the class list for the `.circle` element at each input.

```js
var circleElement = document.querySelector('.circle');
var numberOfPoints = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;

document.getElementById("steering").addEventListener('input', moveCircle);


function moveCircle(event) {
  let inputValue = Number(event.target.value);

  if (inputValue && inputValue <= numberOfPoints) {
    let className = getClassNameFrom(inputValue);

console.clear();
console.log(className);
    
    circleElement.classList = "circle " + className;
  }
}

function getClassNameFrom(inputValue) {
  switch(inputValue) {
    case 1:  return 'one';  
    case 2:  return 'two';  
    case 3:  return 'three';  
    case 4:  return 'four';  
    default: return '';
  } 
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  
  transition:
    left 600ms,
    top 1000ms;
}

.circle,
li {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.one {
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
}

.two {
  left: 150px;
  top: 30px;
}

.three {
  left: 70px;
  top: 70px;
}

.four {
  left: 130px;
  top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="steering" min="1" onfocus="this.select()" />

<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one">1</li>
    <li class="two">2</li>
    <li class="three">3</li>
    <li class="four">4</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great code thank you! But how can I focus on a "click" event of a button now?

Comment: Can you please update your original post to show an image of what it should look like or add HTML code? You can just create a button and add a listener to it pointing to `moveCircle()`, but instead of getting the value from `event.target.value`, you search for the input element by it's id and gets the value from that.

Comment: I didnt made a finished html right now. Maybe that should be the first thing. 

All in one I want to simulate a sorting machine. 
one task is to move a container in a specific place
another is to get a number of how many container are in this specific place 
and one is to get a container from that place.

Maybe now you have an idea of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around with your code, it seems to work perfectly fine, as you can see in this Snippet. I think you may be trying to get some value out of an input field, but if that's so, you need to show what code you've written so far so we can see what the issue is.

```js
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var boxfünf = [{
      transform: 'translate(0, 0)',
    },
    {
      transform: 'translate(0px, -48px)',
    },
    {
      transform: 'translate(-18px, -48px)',
    },
    {
      transform: 'translate(0px, -48px)',
    },
    {
      transform: 'translate(0px, 0px)',
    },
    {
      transform: 'translate(300px, 0px)',
    }
  ];

  var circle = document.getElementById('circle');
  var text = document.getElementById("q");

  document.querySelector('#interaktiv')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      circle.animate(boxfünf, {
        iterations: 1,
        fill: 'forwards',
        duration: 3000,
      });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.circle {
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" id="circle"></div>
<div id="q">text</div>

<button id="interaktiv">interaktiv</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my Code so far.

The idea is to made a simulation of a sorting machine. On click I want to move a container in a certain place. I want to get the value of that place(how many container are in there). And I want to make orders(get a container from that certain place if there is one)

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de'>

    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <meta name='description' content=''>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='animation.css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="number" id="steering" min="1" onfocus="this.select()" />
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Check">  </input>
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li class="one">1</li>
                <li class="two">2</li>
                <li class="three">3</li>
                <li class="four">4</li>
            </ul>

            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="room"></div>
        <div class="room1"></div>
        <div class="room2"></div>
        <div class="room3"></div>
        <div class="room4"></dic>
        
    </body>
    <script src="animation.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
CSS
.container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .circle {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    left: 500px;
    top: 1000px;
    
    transition:
      left 600ms,
      top 1000ms;
  }
  
  .circle,
  li {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .one {
    left:320px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  
  .two {
    left: 320px;
    top: 140px;
  }
  
  .three {
    left: 320px;
    top: 230px;
  }
  
  .four {
    left: 320px;
    top: 320px;
  }
  .click{
      position: absolute;
      top:20px;
      left:180px;
  }
.room{
  width: 1800px;
  height:900px;
  border:8px solid;
  color: green;
}
.room1{
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border:8px solid;
  position:absolute; top:20px; left:10px;
  color:black;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;

}
.room2{
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border:8px solid;
  position:absolute; top:110px; left:10px;
  color:black;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;

}
.room3{
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border:8px solid;
  position:absolute; top:200px; left:10px;
  color:black;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;

}
.room{
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border:8px solid;
  position:absolute; top:290px; left:10px;
  color:black;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#steering{
  position: absolute; top: 1000px; left: 70px;
}
#button{
  position: absolute; top: 1000px; left: 240px;
}
```

```
JS
'use strict'

var circleElement = document.querySelector('.circle');
var numberOfPoints = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
var vsteering = document.getElementById('steering');
var button = document.getElementById('button');


var klick = document.getElementById("button");

klick.addEventListener("click",moveCircle);

function moveCircle() {
  let inputValue = Number(vsteering.value);

  if (inputValue <= numberOfPoints ) {                   
    let className = getClassNameFrom(inputValue);

console.clear();
console.log(className);
    
    circleElement.classList = "circle " + className;
  }
}

function getClassNameFrom(inputValue) {
  switch(inputValue) {
    case 1:  return 'one';  
    case 2:  return 'two';  
    case 3:  return 'three';  
    case 4:  return 'four';  
    default: return '';
  } 
}
```